# The word "period" automatically inserts itself into sentences

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have a Samsung Galaxy S6.  Suddenly when I am typing a message  email  facebook or even in messenger the word (period) inserts itself.
 I did not type the word period nor did I even say the word it's just there. Can somebody please help me get rid of it. It is even in this question I'm asking after the word itself I did not put or say the word period.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that At the end of sentences, the word "period" is added just in front of the actual period? I've edited them out of your question for now :)

Comment: The word period shows up in the middle of sentences.

Comment: What keyboard are you using?

Comment: Perhaps if you leave it in people can see how it randomly appears just my thought. Thank you for your response it is driving me crazy

Comment: You don't answer questions, what keyboard are you using

Comment: Ok Lynn, understood. Could you please answer esqmo though? It's a good thing to know. If you haven't changed the keyboard, just say so :)

Comment: I am using my Galaxy S6 Samsung Android I didn't answer the question because I didn't see it. I hope somebody can give me some advice period I'm tired of having to go back in and delete the word period  through out my email correspondence my messenger and my text message I don't understand why this suddenly happen. I did not go back and delete it from here as it did show up again. Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: This is the original keyboard that came with my cell phone.

Comment: I am still hopeful that I can get an answer to this question. If not do you have any suggestions of where I can take my phone to get this fixed very annoyed period thank you. After the word annoyed there it is the word. Just randomly inserted

Comment: Do you mean "." ??